# unexpected use of low performance transition property (height)

Tags: css, sass, less, lint, scss-lint

```
.sampleClass {
  transition: height 1s cubic-bezier(0.19, 01, 0.1, 0.01);
}
```

I am trying to use the transition property like above but when I run the lint checks it throws the following error and similar errors when using `width` or `all`

```
 126:15  ⚠  Unexpected use of     plugin/no-low-performance-animation-properties
           low performance                                                     
           transition property                                                 
           (height).
```

Answer (score 0):

Some ways of transitioning encourage the system to use the GPU where possible - though this is a complex subject so difficult to lay down hard and fast rules for all cases.

In this particular instance you may like to try transition on a scaleY rather than a height and see if that is more acceptable. This specific idea is discussed in `https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/12/gpu-animation-doing-it-right/` where they give this example -

```
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>

<style>
#a, #b {
 will-change: transform;
}

#a {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
}

#b {
 width: 10px;
 height: 10px;
 transform: scale(10);
}
</style>
```

the second (scale) version being 100 times smaller than the first (separated out). Of course you will want to use scaleY for your height example.

It's worth reading the article and picking up a few tips on what may be best in a particular instance. One thing that is stated is that CSS animations use the GPU, I don't know enough to recommend definite ways forward, try it and lint will tell you I guess.

Answer (score 0):

That's telling you that a transition on the "height" property is a really expensive operation from a performance standpoint.

Animating `height`, `width`, or child content that impacts the size of an element, forces the browser to re-calculate positions of all elements and repaint the page. If you're trying to do that calculation for each frame of animation it's likely to get janky.

This is a bit old, but the main concepts still apply [HTML5Rocks High-Performance Animations](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/).

The goal is to animate properties that can be done with minimal layout changes. Typically this means changing things outside the DOM flow (`scale()`, `translate()`, etc)